# Distribution of convex combination of Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $Y_1,Y_2, \ldots $ are i.i.d Bernoulli$(p)$. What is the distribution of 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{Y_i}{2^i}$$
I could deal case for $p=\frac{1}{2}$ using characteristic functions but for other $p$ I have been struggling with that approach.
Any hints?

Comment: What kind of answer are you expecting? For every $p\ne\frac12$ in $(0,1)$, one gets a probability measure on $(0,1)$ with no atom and singular.

Comment: I am not comfortable with the details of measure theory in all these respects. Can we get a closed form distribution of the above?

Comment: Meaning a closed form of $\mu(B)$ for every Borel subset $B$ of $(0,1)$? No.